# Is there a way to indent just the first line of wrapped text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I know I can pad the start with spaces ( ) but I want to instead indent with a configurable width.

If I add padding to the widget, every line is indented the same, which is not desired.

The result should be like this, but with a configurable width for the first line indent.

```
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore manga 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a WidgetSpan like this:

```
TextSpan(
  children: [
    WidgetSpan(child: SizedBox(width: 40.0)),
    TextSpan(text: 'lorem impsum...'),
  ],
)
```

Comment: what would be the solution if the second line which is soft wrapped needs an indent of configurable width?

Comment: @blazebnayak, that is much more complicated, but there’s a Flutter package that can help called “float_column”. With float_column you can “float” widgets to the left or right of text, like the CSS float feature. So, you could have a SizedBox with a width of the indent amount and height of a little less than two lines and float it so the text indents and wraps around it. Full disclosure, float_column is a package I wrote a few months ago to solve a similar problem, and it is available on pub.dev.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using string interpolation like this `'${' ' * 5}lorem ipsum...'`. You can obviously change the number to as many times as you want.

Comment: I don't want to use space characters, but rather a configurable width (10px, etc.).

Comment: Unfortunately that's not quite possible. At least not to my knowledge.